# How to screengrab from Cisco SPA504g phone?

Tags: cisco, voip

Is it possible to screengrab from a Cisco SPA504g phone?  I'm wanting to make user manuals which have the exact thing the users will see.

Would be convenient for remote checking of provisioning too, but not necessary.

I'm [told](https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/collaboration-voice-and-video/how-to-take-a-screen-shot-from-a-cisco-ip-phone/ta-p/3120882) the older 79xx phones delivered screenshots at

```
http://phone-ip-address/CGI/Screenshot
```

Is there a similar URL for the SPA504g?

System is Asterisk 14.7.5, phones have software version 7.6.2a.

Many thanks.

Comment: I've been using these devices for years and never saw anything that would allow for a screenshot. I suspect it's not possible.

Comment: @michael ... I'd started to believe that too, but found it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd given up on this, but stumbled across the answer:

`http://*phone-ip-address*/admin/screendump.bmp`

Ref from Cisco [forums](https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/small-business-support-documents/spa50x-and-spa30x-screen-dump-screen-scrape/ta-p/3294676).

Tested today on SPA504G with software version 7.6.2a.  It's correct right down to the flashing colon of the time and cursor.  It delivers 128 x 64 BMP format.

Be aware that someone looking at the screendumps can see pretty much everything you do on the phone, including the numbers dialled and so on, in real time.  I don't, yet, know how to configure the phone to control access.

[image]

Kind regards,

Jonathan.